# Windows command line mark current directory

Tags: windows, shell, command-line

On the Windows 7 command line I am in directory `A` and I will issue a command which will move me to directory `B`.

I want to quickly go back to `A` though.
How can I mark `A` in the command line and then go back to it from `B`?

I want to do something like:

```
mark .
cd mark
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the pushd/popd commands:

```
c:\> pushd c:\future
c:\> cd some\where\else
c:\some\where\else> popd
c:\future>
```